# Creating a form for editing embedded documents with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm playing around with [MongoMapper](http://mongomapper.com/) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to create a form for an object that has embedded documents.

With ActiveRecord, I'd use `fields_for` but when asked if this would be supported a few months ago, [MongoMapper author John Nunemaker wrote](http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/msg/0c4661e70bb285aa): "Nope and nope. It is really [not] that hard with attr_accessor's."

OK, fair enough, but how do you write the form for this to work?

I'm not interested in using the nested form implementations that are out there because I want to do this the "normal" way as I'm learning about MongoMapper.

My model is simple enough - I've got a Person with embedded documents for email addresses, phone numbers, etc. I do not care about updating existing embedded documents. They can be re-created from the form input each time a Person is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here [Rails MongoMapper EmbeddedDocument Form Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526004/rails-mongomapper-embeddeddocument-form-help), this is a nice solution.