# update_attributes does not remove embedded documents if an array of them has been emptied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

Trying to get a form for adding, editing and removing embedded documents working as described in this question: [Rails + MongoMapper + EmbeddedDocument form help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2526004/586748).

I've got it mostly to work, however, when editing a document, if all embedded documents are removed by clicking the remove link the params object that is passed to the controller does not include the array field at all, so `update_attributes` ignores it thinking that it hasn't been changed, so doesn't actually remove the embedded documents at all.

Has anyone else encountered this? And other than a hacky way of dealing with it on a case by case basis, is there a nice, neat solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's more of a params problem than a MongoMapper problem.

Building off the code in [Rails + MongoMapper + EmbeddedDocument form help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2526004/586748)...

You could try adding a hidden field before all the answers so an array will always come through the params...

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'problem[answers][]' %>
```

And that will come through in your params like...

```
{ "problem" => { "answers" => [""] }
```

But that'll probably error, so perhaps a better way is to just do this in your controller before the `update_attributes`...

```
params[:problem][:answers] ||= []
```

Comment: Your second option is basically the hacky way of dealing with it on a case by case basis that I envisaged.